# SSIS Using Foreach Container in certain way

Tags: ssis

I am trying to use a Foreach Loop Container in SSIS to loop through a small set of rows and set the column 'id' to a variable.

I have the following variables:

- @startNumber = 5
- @maxNumber = 10

Here's how my loop would look in traditional syntax:

```
for (int i = @startNumber; i > @maxNumber ; i++)
```

This is the TSQL code I want to run to update my rows:

```
UPDATE myTable SET id =  i
```

1. Would I use a Foreach ADO Enumeration?
2. What would be my source variable?
3. How would I apply the logic above?
4. Would I include an Execute TSQL Statment for my update?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you help me understand the big picture of what you're trying to accomplish? I can explain how to use the foreach container and such but I want to ensure you're solving the root problem

Comment: What I have is a foxpro table that stores a nextID value. I am storing the nextID value as startNumber and inserting x number of records, which is endNumber. If the nextID value is 10 and I am inserting 10 more records, my endNumber would be 20. If that makes sense...

Comment: Do you need to do the one-at-a-time insert or could you send all 10 rows in at once to VFP with their nextIDs values populated?

Comment: My idea was to do this row by row. The source (SQL) has this id as an empty column and needs to get the nextID from foxpro (destination). Before I populate the destination I need to update the source before putting it in foxpro.

Comment: The foxpro destination's nextID is an identity column that auto-increments and only stores one value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a simple control flow to show you what I think you're after

[image]

I start with an Execute SQL Task to generate a basic table. You would probably have logic here instead to determine the starting number and/or the terminal value

```
if not exists
(
SELECT * FROM sys.tables AS T WHERE T.name = 'FLC'
)
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE dbo.FLC
    (
        currentID int
    );
END
```

3 variables, scoped to package level

[image]

I configure the For Loop (not the foreach as your question has tagged) much as one would a classic for loop. Here I'm assigning a value to my SSIS Variable @currentNumber

[image]

Within my Execute SQL Task (inside the for loop) I am using @currentNumber as a parameter to my task.

```
INSERT INTO
    dbo.FLC
(
    currentID
)
-- OLE DB & ODBC connections use ? for ordinal parameter
-- ADO.NET uses named parameters like @foo
SELECT ? AS currentID;
```

[image]

Comment: That looks golden! This is what I was looking for! I'm applying it now to my package. I really, really appreciate your help. God bless your brother!