# SSIS For Loop resetting the variable value

Tags: visual-studio-2010, variables, for-loop, ssis

In SSIS (MS Visual Studio 2010) I have created a SQL Task with Single Row output (int32) that is passed to User::Variable. Then I have a "For Loop" that I want to run as many times as the integer from the SQL Task query equals to. I have setup the For Loop with the following:

```
InitExpression: @Start = 1
EvalExpression: @Variable >= @Start
AssignExpression: @Start = @Start+1
```

In my test example, the @Variable is set to 4 by SQL Task query, and the loop runs fine for the first loop, but then immediately finishes reporting package successfully executed (after just 1 loop when it should have looped 4 times).

It is like the @Variable resets to default value (0) after the first loop is done instead of keeping the original value (4).

How can I fix this?

Comment: What else is assigning values to that variable? Post a pic of your canvas. Your logic should be working.

Comment: You have your logic backwards on your EvalAssignment. [Reference implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798772/ssis-using-foreach-container-in-certain-way/19799265#19799265)

Comment: Nothing else but this SQL code (SELECT COUNT(*)/100000+1 as Variable
FROM ODS.dbo.F_AIRQ_BULK_DUMP) which works fine, I used a Script Text Box to display the variable value as test and it was 4. After the first loop is done, the variable goes to its default value, which I put in as 0. @billinkc why is it backwards, it's a mathematical formula, it shouldn't matter which way it goes as long as the boolean is correct way.

Comment: After putting in Script Tasks showing me the variable value after each step inside the For Loop I was able to determine that the variable resets to 0 immediately after an Execute Process Task is run. That task has nothing to do with the @Variable.

Comment: Looks like the @Variable value is being substituted by Execute Process Task's exit code, not by variable's default value. If I break the Execute Process Task the variable gets value -1073741510. LOL Baffling

Comment: Interesting, renaming the @Variable variable to something else seems to have fixed the issue. L O L

Answer (score 1):

What's more likely: using the name `Variable`, which SSIS defaults to for a new variable, is incompatible with *anything* in an SSIS package or that you've done something that you haven't shown?

I have created a package with two Variables, `Variable` and `Start`. I have populated `Variable` from a SQL Query with the value of 4 and then used a For Loop as described and I did not experience early termination.

My package, variables with design time values set to zero.

[image]

My For Loop Container

[image]

Last iteration of the loop

[image]

### Reproducible results

Biml, the Business Intelligence Markup Language, describes the platform for business intelligence. Here, we're going to use it to describe the ETL. [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com), is a free add on for Visual Studio/BIDS/SSDT that addresses a host of shortcomings with it.

You will need to edit line 3 to be a valid OLE DB Connection Manager for your machine (point to a SQL Server installation and possibly update the Provider)

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <OleDbConnection Name="CM_OLE" ConnectionString="Data Source=localhost\dev2012;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
    </Connections>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="so_25878932" ConstraintMode="Linear">
            <Variables>
                <Variable Name="Variable" DataType="Int32">0</Variable>
                <Variable Name="Start" DataType="Int32">0</Variable>
            </Variables>
            <Tasks>
                <ExecuteSQL ConnectionName="CM_OLE" Name="SQL Variable" ResultSet="SingleRow">
                    <DirectInput>SELECT 4 AS Variable;</DirectInput>
                    <Results>
                        <Result Name="0" VariableName="User.Variable"/>
                    </Results>
                </ExecuteSQL>
                <ForLoop ConstraintMode="Linear" Name="FLC Go">
                    <InitializerExpression>@Start = 1</InitializerExpression>
                    <LoopTestExpression>@Variable >= @Start</LoopTestExpression>
                    <CountingExpression>@Start = @Start + 1</CountingExpression>
                    <Tasks>
                        <!--
                        Pilfered from http://bimlscript.com/Snippet/Details/74
                        -->
                        <Script 
                            ProjectCoreName="ST_232fecafb70a4e8a904cc21f8870eed0" 
                            Name="SCR Emit Variable and Start">
                            <ReadOnlyVariables>
                                <ReadOnlyVariable VariableName="User.Variable" />
                                <ReadOnlyVariable VariableName="User.Start" />
                            </ReadOnlyVariables>
                            <ScriptTaskProject>
                                <ScriptTaskProject ProjectCoreName="ST_c41ad4bf47544c49ad46f4440163feae" Name="TaskScriptProject1">
                                    <AssemblyReferences>
                                        <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll" />
                                        <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="Microsoft.SqlServer.ScriptTask.dll" />
                                        <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.dll" />
                                        <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.AddIn.dll" />
                                        <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Data.dll" />
                                        <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Windows.Forms.dll" />
                                        <AssemblyReference AssemblyPath="System.Xml.dll" />
                                    </AssemblyReferences>
                                    <Files>
                                        <File Path="AssemblyInfo.cs">
                                            using System.Reflection;
                                            using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

                                            //
                                            // General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following
                                            // set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
                                            // associated with an assembly.
                                            //
                                            [assembly: AssemblyTitle("ST_c41ad4bf47544c49ad46f4440163feae.csproj")]
                                            [assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
                                            [assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
                                            [assembly: AssemblyCompany("Varigence")]
                                            [assembly: AssemblyProduct("ST_c41ad4bf47544c49ad46f4440163feae.csproj")]
                                            [assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright @ Varigence 2013")]
                                            [assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
                                            [assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
                                            [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
                                        </File>
                                        <File Path="ScriptMain.cs">
                                            using System;
                                            using System.Data;
                                            using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
                                            using System.Windows.Forms;

                                            // if SSIS2012, use the following line:
                                            [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]

                                            // if earlier version, use the next line instead of the above line:
                                            // [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
                                            public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
                                            {
                                            enum ScriptResults
                                            {
                                            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
                                            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
                                            };

                                            public void Main()
                                            {
                                            int i = 0;
                                            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}:{1}", Dts.Variables[i].Name, Dts.Variables[i].Value));
                                            i++;
                                            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}:{1}", Dts.Variables[i].Name, Dts.Variables[i].Value));
                                            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                                            }
                                            }
                                        </File>
                                    </Files>
                                </ScriptTaskProject>
                            </ScriptTaskProject>
                        </Script>
                        <ExecuteProcess Executable="cmd.exe" Name="EP Do nothing" Arguments="/C">

                        </ExecuteProcess>
                    </Tasks>
                </ForLoop>
            </Tasks>
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

### Root cause guess

Variables can be created at different scopes within a package. I would presume that since a variable is created with the default name of `Variable` two, or more, such variables exist with the same name but at different application scopes. Thus, if I had defined a second SSIS variable named `Variable` on my ForLoop Container, it would start with a value of 0, unless defined otherwise. My package execution would begin, assign the value of 4 to my package level `Variable`. Control switches to my ForLoop Container. The `Variable` defined there wins from a scoping perspective so my value there is 0, not 4 because nothing has initialized it. In that case, the ForLoop would never fire as the terminal condition has already been met. For your case, I further presume that someone initialized that variable to 1.

Notice the Scope here, this is what I believe to be your root cause.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

DO NOT name SSIS variables @Variable. Doing so will unintentionally cause the variable value to pick up exit codes of other processes in the package as they run.

In my case the @Variable value would automatically change to 0 after a successfully run Execute Process Task with exit code 0; or change to -1073741510 when that process run failed.